Issue at loading word document with docx4j
I try to use docx4j to interact with word documents in my program (before I used Apache POI). But I meet an issue at the very beginning. I downloaded the last version of docx4j (11.4). Here is my code:
String path = "input.docx";
File file = new File(path);
try {
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(file);
    HashMap<String, String> mappings = new HashMap<>();
    VariablePrepare.prepare(wordMLPackage);
    mappings. Put("<<<today>>>", new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy").format(new Date()));
    mappings. Put("%", "Hello");
    mappings. Put("#", "Word");
             
    wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().variableReplace(mappings);
    wordMLPackage.save("output.docx");
    
    } catch (Docx4JException e) {
        System.out.println("Docx4JException");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        System.out.println("JAXBException");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }


I have an issue at this line and I don't understand why:
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(file);
Here is the the error log with IntelliJ IDEA:

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.getNextEntry()'
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.stores.ZipPartStore.(ZipPartStore.java:141)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:570)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:421)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:298)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:276)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.load(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:170)
at fr.analyse.assistant.model.Word.printingLetters(Word.java:307)
at fr.analyse.assistant.controllers.VController.letter(VController.java:470)
at fr.analyse.assistant.controllers.VController.lambda$initialize$6(VController.java:215)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8875)
at javafx.controls@21.0.1/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
at javafx.controls@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:207)
at javafx.controls@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3984)
at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1890)
at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2708)
at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

I searched on Google to find out why this happened, but I found nothing. No articles about that issue.
PS: Hope it's understandable

Looks like you have the wrong version of Commons Compress. Have did you determine your versions in the first place? Please make that code into a minrep btw (you're nearly there)

I think the code is now into minrep. You can reproduce it. But as I said, the problem is that line:
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(file);

The wrong version of Commons Compress?! But how? The version of the jar is 1.26 and docx4j is 11.4. They were all in the docx4j community zip file I downloaded from their site.

That can't be your code. It wouldn't compile

and docx4j is 11.4. 11.4.what?

And make sure you have no other clashing versions of dependency jars in your classpath

It's mysterious. The following works perfectly well for me. All I did was get the latest (11.4.11) from Maven of docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl and added it to my pom. See what happens when you run my code with your input file.
package com.technojeeves.docx4j;

import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.model.datastorage.migration.VariablePrepare;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException; 

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "input.docx";
        String outputPath = "output.docx";
        try {
            InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Path.of(path));
            OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(Path.of(outputPath));
            WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(in);
            HashMap<String, String> mappings = new HashMap<>();
            VariablePrepare.prepare(wordMLPackage);
            mappings.put("<<<today>>>", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMMM yyyy", Locale.US).format(LocalDate.now()));
            mappings.put("%", "Hello");
            mappings.put("#", "Word");

            // Don't understand this yet
            wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().variableReplace(mappings);
            wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText("g00se is the greatest!");
            wordMLPackage.save(out);

        } catch (Docx4JException e) {
            System.out.println("Docx4JException");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            System.out.println("JAXBException");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}


Your code runs perfectly, but I when i insert this in my project, the issue appears again. The project is not a maven one because I had conflict between some jars. How can I find which jar is clashing?

The project is not a maven one because I had conflict between some jars. You should make it one. As you can see, I had no conflict problems

I switched to a maven project and reproduced your code but it still not working. There could be a conflict with another jar, but I don't know which one.

Try backing up your local repo, deleting everything below .m2, then do mvn compile exec:java

Sorry! I am not a pro and I don't know where to do mvn compile exec:java. Can you help me please?

First you need to install Maven standalone. What's your OS?

The OS is Windows 11

Well get hold of an installer for Windows and install Maven, that's the first step. Read the docs carefully about setting it up. There are variables to be set, in addition to placing Maven in PATH

I finally found the solution. I post it here in the case of some may encounter same issues. It was as g00se said: a conflict between some jars.
To check those conflicts, I clicked on the maven tab at the right of Intellij IDEA window.

Then, there is a small button "Analyze dependencies".

And from there, I solved all those conflicts and the app runs well.
